# `onLongPressGesture` minimumDuration parameter is ignored in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, gesture

There's a problem with handling the long tap gesture. The idea is to have a both short and long tap on the same view inside `LazyVGrid`. The long tap timing still seems to be `0.5` second which is too long in my case. I tried to reduce it to `0.1` but it seems to be ignored

```
ScrollView {
        Text("Greeting")
        LazyVGrid(columns: ) {
            ForEach(
                models
            ) { model in
                View(
                    model: pointModel
                )
                .onTapGesture {
                    model.didSelect()
                }
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1, perform: {
                    model.didLongTap()
                })
            }
        }
```

I've tried next workarounds:

1. Change the order of long/single taps so that long is defined first. It causes the `ScrollView` to stop scrolling
2. Add a gesture using `.gesture` which made no changes

I expect the minimum duration to be taken into account for the long press action

Answer (score 3):

Use a `simultaneousGesture`:

```
.onTapGesture {
    print("Tap")
}
.simultaneousGesture(
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1).onEnded { _ in
        print("Long Press")
    }
)
```

This will trigger the tap gesture if you press for less than some system-defined duration (the maximum duration that the system thinks a "tap" should last), and will trigger the long press gesture if you press for at least 0.1 seconds.

This means that sometimes both gestures get triggered - when you press for less than the system-defined duration, but more than 0.1 seconds.

If you don't want that, you can implement the tap gesture with a `LongPressGesture` too, just with a very short minimum duration. Then, use `exclusively(before:)` to handle the conflict.

```
let tap = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.0001).onEnded({ _ in
    print("Tap")
    })

let longPress = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1).onEnded({ _ in
    print("Long Press")
    })

YourView()
     // Give longPress more precedence over tap
    .gesture(longPress.exclusively(before: tap))
```